# How do I add a personal script to an existing node.js library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hls.js

I have a local copy of the hls.js library and I need to include a personal script with custom functions in it.
How do I go about adding a new script to the library and how do I use the function written in the new script?
Let's say that I want to add a script called hello.js that contains a function that logs "Hello World". 
When I call that function in my main.js I need it to execute.
Any ideas on how to do this?
Currently, I'm getting an error that the function is not defined.
I placed the hello.js script in the src folder of the library but this (as expected) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can simply export its function and `require` it in your "main" script without having anything to do with the other library. Have a look [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/)

Comment: why do you need to include this personal script on the library itself?

Comment: can you post some of the code that you have done?

Comment: I need it to work as a "native" part of the hls.js library. Meaning that the only require I  should have to type is: var Hls = require('hls.js'). 
If possible of course.

Comment: [y tho?](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/facebook/000/022/978/yNlQWRM.jpg)

Comment: @FabioAntunes I added hello.js to the src folder. The code in hello.js is: 
    exports.printMsg = function() {
      console.log("Hello");
    }
Calling printMsg in my main script just says that it's not defined.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I asked my client the same thing.
Here's the response: "Just do it as requested".

Comment: back on topic, can you modify the source of the library? If so, wrap yours with it by exporting your functions from there.

Comment: My guess is the client wants to override specific labels in HLS with a copyright information which, if that's the case, is completely unethical. Otherwise who would ask such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to add functions to the exported `hls.js` object.

Your custom-script.js:

```js
var hls = require('hls.js')

hls.customFunc1 = function () {
}

hls.customFunc2 = function () {
}
```

on main.js:

```js
require('custom-script')

// your code follows
```

Any other code would be able to use the custom functions by just require'ing `hls.js`.